# SOLVED : drive api in google app script runs into an infinite loop :(

Tags: google-apps-script

I try listing all the files in my drive and it runs into an infinite loop

my code:

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while(folders.hasNext())
  {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var folderName = folder.getName();
    Logger.log(folderName);
  }
```

I tried debugging and it ran into the loop in the first iteration of the loop. Also in my testing I saw it ran into a loop with the next() function as well

I just didn't allow api access smh.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual script, I think that your showing script doesn't occur `it runs into an infinite loop`. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating `it runs into an infinite loop`? For example, I think that if you have a lot of folders, all folders are returned and the folder names are shown in the log. Is that your expected result? By the way, can I ask you about your expected result in this question?